# achemso package: referencing multiple figures

Tags: cross-referencing, achemso

I am using the `achemso` package to submit a paper to Environmental Science and Technology. When I include a reference to a figure (`\ref{Fig1}`), the figure number appears preceded by the word "Figure." I would like to reference "Figures 1-2", but using `\ref{Fig1,Fig2}` gives an error and `\ref{Fig1}-\ref{Fig2}` gives "Figure 1-Figure 2."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have an old version of `achemso` installed. For various reasons I dropped some time ago the 'auto-magic' addition of 'Figure' or similar to cross-references. The current release doesn't do this, so would just require _e.g._ `Figures~\ref{fgr:one}--\ref{fgr:two}`. Note that as the ACS re-typeset your papers once accepted, there is not really a big issue here in any case (other than the fact that referees sometimes comment on this sort of thing even though it's not actually an issue!).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `cleveref` package and the `\cref` command. It automatically sorts and compress the references. For instance, typesetting `\cref{Fig1, Fig5, Fig2, Fig3}` will print
`figures 1-3 and 5` (if they're labelled so). If later your figures become another structure (say a  table), the names will change accordingly. It has a multilingual support.

For the current versions of `achemso` and `cleveref` (7/2015), this looks like the following. You might want to read the `cleveref` manual on how to get a hyphen instead of the word "to".

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{achemso}
\title{title}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{captioneins}\label{fig:labeleins}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{captionzwei}\label{fig:labelzwei}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{captiondrei}\label{fig:labeldrei}
\end{figure}

\Cref{fig:labeleins}, \cref{fig:labeleins,fig:labelzwei}, \cref{fig:labeleins,fig:labeldrei}, and \cref{fig:labeleins,fig:labelzwei,fig:labeldrei}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Won't work here. Older versions of `achemso` load either `cleverref` or `varioref` implicitly, but that caused various issues so I dropped it!

Comment: @JosephWright please see my edit above. Looks as if this is working fine at the moment. Or do you see some drawbacks for `cleveref` used with your documentclass?

Comment: According to the manual, `\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}` will replace the `to` for a dash.